# Chinese of “No one will think you’re mute because you don’t speak”

Tags: expressions, idioms

Does anyone know the correct Chinese expression that goes something like no one would think you’re mute because you don’t speak? And how it’s correctly written in Chinese?

I’ve read the translation a few times and wanted to read the original words/see the characters. Thanks!!

Comment: "No one will think you're mute *because* you don't speak" sounds like a more natural translation to me, given the original Chinese meaning stated in the answers.

Answer (score 7):

The one comes to mind:

> 你不说话没人把你当哑巴。

你 can be omitted:

> 不说话没人把你当哑巴。

Answer (score 5):

the cantonese version is “唔出聲，冇人話你啞”

have fun :)

[ng4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/ng4.Mp3) | 唔

[shut1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/ceot1.Mp3) | 出

[seng1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/seng1.Mp3) | 聲

[mo5](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/mou5.Mp3) | 冇

[yan4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/jan4.Mp3) | 人

[wa6](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/waa6.Mp3) | 話

[nei5](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/nei5.Mp3) | 你

[a2](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/aa2.Mp3) | 啞

Comment: Since we are having fun, how about putting the Cantonese pronunciation here for the benefit of non-Cantonese speakers? I can imagine people here trying to read that in Mandarin, especially 冇

Comment: @ wayne cheah done 

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Thank you, @dan and @水巷孑蠻! This is such fun phrase to me.